# Como resuelvo el error de ``java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otmcjni in java.library.path``

Tags: java, jframe, rutas

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de mi universidad y tengo una computadora allá y lo corre muy bien pero descargue el proyecto y me lo traje a mi computadora personal pero no me corre como en la otra y me da muchos errores.

Aquí están todos los que me dan:

> `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no otmcjni in java.library.path  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.(MatchingLibrary.java:16)
>     at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher.(Matcher.java:8)
>     at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl$EnrollmentImpl.(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.createEnrollment(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:20)
>     at labmovile.FrmUsuario.(FrmUsuario.java:45)  at
>   labmovile.FrmPrincipal.(FrmPrincipal.java:10)   at
>   labmovile.FrmPrincipal$7.run(FrmPrincipal.java:294)   at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.init()V   at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.init(Native Method)
>     at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.(MatchingLibrary.java:36)
>     at
>   com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.(MatchingLibrary.java:20)
>     at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher.(Matcher.java:8)

Por favor tengo muy poco tiempo para entregarlo y llevo mucho tiempo investigando.

Comment: Hola! Puedes compartir el código que está produciendo ese error?

Comment: Estando en tu universidad añadiste alguna librería al proyecto??

Comment: Podrías intentar configurar en el panel de Control de JAVA en la pantalla de avanzado, la opción de "ver consola" con ello verías desde que ubicación se está intentando cargar tu aplicación JAVA, en esa misma ubicación podrías ubicar la librería que te marca como faltante para que logre encontrarla, funcionó para mi.